# Trying to understand how display images with a custom Drupal theme

Tags: html, css, drupal, theming

I'm trying to understand how create a Drupal 8 custom theme. I've some questions about that, and i can't find a real answer on documentation or else. Can somebody help me please ?

I've created a libraries.yml and theme_info.yml with theses informations :

```
name: Cosplay Academy
type: theme
description: 'A cuddly theme that offers extra fluffiness.'
core: 8.x
libraries:
- cosplayacademy/global-styling-and-scripts
regions:
  header: Header
  primary_menu: 'Primary menu'
  secondary_menu: 'Secondary menu'
  page_top: 'Page top'
  page_bottom: 'Page bottom'
  highlighted: Highlighted
  featured_top: 'Featured top'
  breadcrumb: Breadcrumb
  content: Content
  sidebar_first: 'Sidebar first'
  sidebar_second: 'Sidebar second'
  featured_bottom_first: 'Featured bottom first'
  featured_bottom_second: 'Featured bottom second'
  featured_bottom_third: 'Featured bottom third'
  footer_first: 'Footer first'
  footer_second: 'Footer second'
  footer_third: 'Footer third'
  footer_fourth: 'Footer fourth'
  footer_fifth: 'Footer fifth'
```

```
global-styling-and-scripts:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      css/plugins/bootstrap.min.css: {}
      css/style.css: {}
      css/skin-modes.css: {}
      css/icons.css: {}
      css/plugins/horizontal-menu.css: {}
      css/colors/color6.css: {}
```

I see my css files in my html markup, but there is a lot of css files before it. Why ? Can i remove them ?

Also, i'm trying to display an image into a data-image-src and it won't shows up :/ When i look at my html markup and when i copy the image url, it's work, i can see it, but i can't see it into my page... I'm totally lost :/

As you can see below, my css files are loaded at the end, and my image doesn't appeared...

[image: No image on my page]

[image: Drupal CSS Files]

Answer (score 0):

**Extra css files:**
The extra css files you are seeing are added by drupal core and various modules that have been enabled. I can see by what css files are included, that you are logged in when viewing this page, which, for example, has made the toolbar css be included on the page. Most of these css files would not be included when viewing the page as an anonymous user.
You should not worry about these, when putting the site live, you would set css and javascript aggregation under the "performance" settings and these would be combined into just a few files and only include what is needed.

**data-img-src:**
I am not sure what you are expecting to happen by adding 'data-img-src' ??
To set the image path on an img tag, you just use the 'src' attribute.
Any attribute that begins with 'data-' is just meant to be a data store, that, for example, you may want to use with some javascript.

**More info on data attributes:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes
https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Answer (score 0):

Regarding removing of Drupal stylesheets in your custom theme... you can add something like this into your .info.yml

```
stylesheets-remove:
  - core/assets/vendor/normalize-css/normalize.css
  - core/modules/system/css/system.module.css
  - core/modules/system/css/system.theme.css
  - core/modules/views/css/views.module.css
```

to have them removed.